# API Route vs API utility function in NextJS13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

What's the best practice in calling external API in NextJS 13? Create a server utility function where its imported into multiple UI components / pages or write a new API route handlers and fetch it in UI components? And why?

I am having difficulties understanding the use of route handlers if utility API functions will also just do the work on fetching data from server.